# Whirlpool Electic Oven AKP 458/NB heating elements not shutting off on desired temperature

Tags: thermostat, oven

The problem began when I was baking some cookies. I was keeping an eye on them when suddenly I noticed they were starting to burn. The top and bottom elements decided to just stay on. I am glad I caught this because I am certain they would stay on and cause significant damage. Now, it doesn't matter what option the oven selector is set to; conventional, broiler, convection, etc. The element light comes on even with the temperature control knob OFF. Of course, turning the selector to OFF turns off the oven, and the timer/clock functions as it should, although one day I saw that it was blinking as if the power went off. I thought that was weird. I replaced the thermostat/temp control with the temp probe thinking this was the problem, but it didn't fix it. I am starting to think that the timer/clock control (or control board) is the problem. But I just can't understand in my mind why this thing being defective would keep both heating elements on all the time when oven selector is on desired option (not when it's OFF). Therefore, I am looking for some help and advice here. Someone else mentioned that I should check all the wiring to the thermostat, but I see no problems there. Does anyone else have any ideas how this just happened? Could it be the timer/clock control board?

Comment: Sounds like a control board issue.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the reply. Unfortunately, a replacement is not available. So I will try to test it and see if I can single out the bad component, most likely a frozen relay. It could still be a wiring issue somewhere, and I am trying to study the schematic to see what would cause the thermostat to be completely bypassed.